# Sheet dismiss listener in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I pick the image from gallery using sheet. I want to call function (uploadToServer()) after pick the image

My code: .

```
sheet(isPresented: $isImagePickerShown) {
        ImagePickerController(sourceType: self.sourceType, inputImage: self.$image, inputImageUrl: $imageURL)
          //I want to get the selected imageURL here to call uploadToServer()
    }
```

How can I get url after sheet dismissed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use it in callback, like

```
sheet(isPresented: $isImagePickerShown, onDismiss: {
   // use `self.imageURL` here to upload to server
   uploadToServer(url: self.imageURL)   // << eg.
}) {
        ImagePickerController(sourceType: self.sourceType, inputImage: self.$image, inputImageUrl: $imageURL)
          //I want to get the selected imageURL here to call uploadToServer()
    }
```